# python json.loads() works but requests.json does not work, on an odata endpoint that produces 32MB of json

Tags: python, json, python-requests, odata

Have been happily using requests.json interchangably with json.loads().... but today I was using an odata endpoint that returns ~ 32MB of json...  json.loads() worked fine but when I tried requests.json it raised an error.  So there must be differences between the two?  Any insights on what these might be...   Using python 3.6, requests 2.18.4

```
# get json from odata endpoint and check for top-level "value" element...
try:
    http_response = requests.get( url )
except Exception as errmsg:
    sys.exit( "Error on http request ... Msg: " + str(errmsg) )

try:
    # jsondata  = json.loads( http_response.text )   # works fine
    jsondata = http_response.json                  # doesn't work
except Exception as errmsg:
    sys.exit( "Error on json conversion: " + str(errmsg) )

 try:
    rowset = jsondata["value"]
except Exception as errmsg:
    sys.exit( "ERROR .... can't find 'value'. Msg: " + str(errmsg) )
```

The odata endpoint I need to call returns json that is lengthy (32,113,432 chars) and begins like this:

```
  {"@odata.context":"http://xxx.yyy.org/JAXLIMS/Odata /$metadata#MPDInputs","@odata.count":27775,"value":[{"C_InputInstance_key":19203327,"InputValue":"129","InputName":"Experimenter", ....etc....
```

The error raised when I use requests.json is:

```
ERROR .... can't find 'value'. Msg: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: First, how are you calling `json.loads`? Second, can you show us what `page.content` (or whatever) shows when `page.json()` fails?

Comment: You should share specific code and specific data inputs.  It sounds as if there's some subtle difference, so the details will matter.

Comment: Also, don't just tell us "returned an error", copy and paste the full exception. There's no way to guess whether it's a problem with character decoding or JSON decoding or something completely different without knowing what failed.

Comment: Consider deleting the question in the interim -- that way it doesn't garner downvotes or close votes. If you delete it yourself (vs having it closed and deleted by vote, which would require another vote to reopen), you can undelete it after it's been edited to have enough details to be answerable.